# why is my tomcat console dying just after starting up?

Tags: tomcat, command-line, tomcat8

when i run my tomcat this way

"$TOMCAT_HOME\bin\catalina.bat jpda start

The window goes ,away in fractions of second without giving the errors.SO it is hard to know the underlying reasons, if any.

Answer (score 1):

I found that after changing from

"$TOMCAT_HOME\bin\catalina.bat jpda run

to

"$TOMCAT_HOME\bin\catalina.bat jpda start

the tomcat starts in the same window , and it prints the issue

For me it was binding issue with the target port so i changed to some other port.